# How to make a GridView stretchable in Android to expand the Column width to any extend?

Tags: android

Anyone please help me with some code snippets to slove the problem.If anyone knows how to make an adjustable gridview please help me.

Answer (score 13):

If you've set a specific number of columns and want the columns to expand as necessary, try [`gridView.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#setStretchMode%28int%29).

If you've instead set a specific column width and want the number of columns to change as necessary, use [`gridView.setNumColumns(GridView.AUTO_FIT)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#setNumColumns%28int%29).

Comment: Straight-forward and clear. You've explained this better than the official docs Android has for GridView. Bravo!

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding strechMode in XML , it can be done

```
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
```