# How to align name:values pairs as ListView item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I need to show a list of name:value pairs in ListView. And I want to align values to longest name width. But length of names and its count is unknown until data is received.

For example:

```
name1:          value1
name111:        value2
someOtherName:  value3
----------------------next ListView Item
name3:          value4
longestNameeee: value5
----------------------next ListView Item
```

For now I've created Adapter with LinearLayout as item layout and I'm adding inner LinearLayouts with name - value pairs with weigth 0.5 - 0.5 (means values shows after middle of layout).
But how to set name - value weights according to longest name length?

Comment: What about using a two-column gridview, where a column is of the same width for all rows. Here is a suggestion about how to control column widths in GridView: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985153/how-to-make-a-gridview-stretchable-in-android-to-expand-the-column-width-to-any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can consider using a relative layout in you listview row layout and align the name to the left and value to the right?

Another option might be to can use Paint.measureText to measure text length - but to need to set the paint properties that same as the textview display properties (textSize, texyStyle,font,...)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#measureText(java.lang.String, int, int)

you should be able to get a decent measurement of the text length using this - it give you a sixe in pixels Which you can use to set the layout params of all the name textViews in your list rows.

Answer (score 0):

---

Do you need the values to commence exactly after the longest name? Or just to be able to show that longest name? Well what I would suggest (and did in a similar problem) is not using a LinearLayout, but a RelativeLayout.

In there you would define two TextViews, one of which would have gravity on the right. From what I can see from your code, the right field is always same size, correct? So, adjust it according to that and let the left space free to be filled. 
An example layout of mine:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="3dip" >

<!-- Name-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="20dip"
    android:text="Name"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<!-- Amount -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/amount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:text="money"
    android:textSize="20dip"
    android:textColor="#FF8B1500"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The right TextView fills as much space as it needs and the left is left for the names.

hope I helped giving an idea!